# PHP mysql Как сохранить выбранное значение selected option в session

Tags: php, mysql

В `session` попадает всегда последнее значение `while`.
Как можно сделать чтоб в session попало выбранное значение?

```
 <input name='date_t'  type="hidden"  value='<? echo $item['goods_id']?>'>
  <?php $id =  $item['goods_id']; ?>
  <select name="data" >
  <option>Выберите Дату</option>
<?
 $res = mysql_query("select date_trip from dates_trip  where goods_t_id='$id'");
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
?>
 <option  value="<?=$row['date_trip']?>"> <?=$row['date_trip']?></option>
<?
     $_SESSION['data'] = $row['date_trip'];
}
?>
 </select>
<? echo $_SESSION['data'];  ?>
```

Comment: Пример покажите?

Comment: `$_SESSION['data'][]` наверное стоит сделать

Answer (score 1):

Выбранное значение необходимо сохранять после отправки данных формы на сервер. В вашем примере `back-end` сохранит последнее значение итерации массива опций, на выбор значения клиентом это никак не повлияет.

Пример отправки данных формы в качестве `POST` запроса

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZKbQb

---

В контексте вашей реализации

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['data'])) $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data']; ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input name='date_t'  type="hidden"  value='<? echo $item['goods_id']?>'>
  <?php $id =  $item['goods_id']; ?>
  <select name="data" >
  <option>Выберите Дату</option>
<?
 $res = mysql_query("select date_trip from dates_trip  where goods_t_id='$id'");
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
?>
 <option  value="<?=$row['date_trip']?>"> <?=$row['date_trip']?></option>
?>
 </select>
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<? if (isset($_SESSION['data']))
     echo $_SESSION['data'];  ?>
```